# ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'function'>

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

```
def clean_driver_data(driver_data_new,policy_data,selected_customer,snapshot,product):      

    data_org = pd.merge(policy_data,driver_data_new,how='left',left_on=['EXT_POL_SFX_CONCAT_CD','POL_EFF_DT'],right_on=['EXT_POL_SFX_CONCAT_CD','EFF_DT'])
```

I have called this function and later I am merging the date into data_org I am getting the following error

Comment: In your code you either have function with name `policy_data` or `driver_data_new`.

Comment: Kindly provide with a sample of the dataframes you wish to merge